# Show Tensorboard time series for large images

Tags: tensorboard

I would like to visualize a large image which consists of 50 128x128 images in a rectangle in the time series visualization of tensorboard, but it clips the image due to the tensorboard card being too small vertically. As shown.

[image: Card clipped vertically.]

In the Tensorboard Images tab, the card stretches down properly to the image height.

[image: Stretched Properly to image height.]

Is there any way to stretch the card to the actual image height as in the images tab? I've tried looking through the settings, but I can't find any simple solution. I would ideally like to use the time series if I can as it allows for pins and loads slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

For me, downgrading tensorboard=2.9.0 works